# WinForm App Crashes when I click Preview of Crystal Report

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, crash

I am facing a very critical problem in days which is, everything was running fine. But in the morning, my win app crashed when the user wanted to get a print of Crystal Report. I have installed CRRunTime32bit version and 64bit version too, but somehow, when I click on preview from Development machine it prints, but on client system app crashes and following details have been shown on screen.

```
Problem Event Name: CLS20r3
Problem Signature 01: MyApp.exe
Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03: 58ef7d21
Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
Problem Signature 05: 4.0.0.0
Problem Signature 06: 4ba1da6f
Problem Signature 07: 2463
Problem Signature 08: 0
Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
LocaleID: 1033
```

Comment: did you create a sample app to reproduce this?

Comment: I found a solution which is, CR Run Time Version doesn't support Framework 4, so i converted my App into 3.5 and my problem resolved.